# Orthogonal lines and rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Is to possible to modify the code to just specify points A, B and C, then draw a right angle from C just giving a length and find a point D, then by specifying an angle and lenght to find a point E and draw the segments.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(1.5,2){D}
\tkzDefPoint(2,3){E}

\tkzDrawSegments(A,B C,D)
\tkzDrawSegment[color=red](C,E)

\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](D){$D$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](E){$E$}

\tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C,D,E)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can place points D with:

- a rotation of center C and angle pi/2 of point B, we obtain B'
- draw the half-line BB'
- draw a circle with center C and radius 2
- the point of intersection is point D

We proceed in the same way for point E.

We have in `tkz-euclide`:

- `\tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center C angle 90](B)`
- `\tkzDefCircle[R](C,2)`
- `\tkzInterLC`

We can also use `tkz-elements`, requires compilation in `lualatex`

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tkzelements}
  local lengthCD = 2
  local lengthCE = 3
  local angBCE = math.pi/3
  z.A = point: new (0,0)
  z.B = point: new (3,0)
  L.AB = line : new (z.A,z.B)
  z.C = L.AB.mid
  --
  z.Bp = z.C : rotation (math.pi/2,z.B)
  L.CBp = line : new (z.C,z.Bp)
  C.CD = circle : radius (z.C,lengthCD)
  z.D,_ = intersection (L.CBp,C.CD)
  --
  z.Bpp = z.C : rotation (angBCE,z.B)
  L.CBpp = line : new (z.C,z.Bpp)
  C.CE = circle : radius (z.C,lengthCE)
  z.E,_ = intersection (L.CBpp,C.CE)
  \end{tkzelements}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines](0,0)grid(3,4);
  \tkzGetNodes

\tkzDrawSegments(A,B C,D)
\tkzDrawSegment[color=red](C,E)

\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](D){$D$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](E){$E$}

\tkzDrawPoints[gray](A,...,E)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simply to solved using `tikz` with library `calc`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {circle, fill=gray, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {text=black}
                        ]
\node[label= left:$A$] (a) at (0,0) {};
\node[label=right:$B$] (b) at (3,0) {};
\draw   (a) -- (b);
\node[label=below:$C$] (c) at (1.5,0) {};
% line perpendicular to line a -- b from point c
\draw   (c) -- ($(c)!20mm!90:(b)$) node[label=D] {}; 
% drawn with selected angle (for example 60 degree)  from point c
\draw[red]   (c) -- ($(c)!30mm!60:(b)$) node[label=E] {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or a case, when line a -- b is not horizontal:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {circle, fill=gray, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {text=black}
                        ]
\node[label= left:$A$] (a) at (0,0) {};
\node[label=right:$B$] (b) at (3,1) {};
\draw   (a) -- (b);
\node[label=below:$C$] (c) at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$)  {};
%
\draw   (c) -- ($(c)!20mm!90:(b)$) node[label=D] {};
%
\draw[red]   (c) -- ($(c)!30mm!60:(b)$) node[label=E] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doubtless there is a `tkz-euclide` syntax, but I don't speak French, so I stick to Ti*k*Z methods.

The following image superimposes the results of implementing the alternative procedure requested over the results of the original method.

[image: superimposed alternate method]

Obviously, you do not need the original points or the `scope` if substituting new code for old.

I don't know if I picked the intended point to find `E`, but you can adapt the method to take whichever point you need as the base.

```
\documentclass{standalone}   
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(1.5,2){D}
  \tkzDefPoint(2,3){E}
  
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,B C,D)
  \tkzDrawSegment[color=red](C,E)
  
  \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[below](C){$C$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[above](D){$D$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[above](E){$E$}
  
  \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray](A,B,C,D,E)
  
  \begin{scope}[draw=blue,every label/.append style=blue]
    \path (C) ++(0pt,2) coordinate [label=above:$D$] (d);
    \path (d) ++(63:1.12) coordinate [label=above:$E$] (e);
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,B C,d C,e)
  \end{scope}

  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```